# How to receive data and send back signal using goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I want to make use of **concurrency** in Go to send data to a goroutine for processing and computation **using channels**. The data points come one after another in a function which can be main function or some `sendData` function.   **If possible, I would like to have the sending of the data to be done from main function.**

I want to send the data from the send function to a goroutine, where data is stored in a slice (lets call this goroutine `getData`). Certain computations are done on this slice. **After a certain condition is reached (which depends on the slice), I want the goroutine to signal the `sendData` function that processing is complete for a certain batch of data points.** And now, the `sendData` function keeps sending data points through the channel to `getData` goroutine where a new slice keeps getting built and when the condition is reached the signal is sent - that processing is complete and the entire sequence keeps getting repeated.

As an example, lets imagine that data in the form of numbers is being sent from `sendData` to `getData`. The condition is that the running mean of numbers received by `getData` should be equal to 4. Lets take the following sequence of numbers as our data - `[]int{3, 2, 3, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15}`. Here, the first batch of numbers would be `{3, 2, 3, 8}` because after these numbers are sent in this sequence to `getData`, it finds that the running mean of numbers is equal to 4 after the number 8 is received by `getData`. Then it sends a signal to `sendData`. And the process of sending data starts again in sequence of numbers with the next batch being `{2, 1, 1, 1, 15}`. Here, after the number `15` is received by `getData` it finds that the running mean is equal to 4 an sigal is sent again to `sendData`. **( This is a very basic example - in my real use case, the input data and the condition are more complex. I have data which will be read live in `sendData`. Here each data point is read sequentially but each data point arrives at a few microseconds after the previous one. As such the arrival of data is fast paced here, and I don't want to do too much of processing and calculations in this function. Furthermore, I want keep concurrency intact, because in the function where data is being read, data is arriving at a fast rate. And, I don't want the reading of data here to be missed because of the processing of data in the goroutine where processing is done.)**

Here is how I have tried to structure the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go sendData(ch)
    go getData(ch)
}

func sendData(ch chan int) {
    syntheticData := []int{3, 2, 3, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15}
    for _, data := range syntheticData {
            ch <- data
        }
}

func getData(ch chan int) {
        dataArr := []int{}
        dataArr = append( dataArr, <-ch )
        fmt.Println(dataArr)

        if mean(dataArr) == 4{
          close(ch)
        }

}

func sum(array []int) int {
    var result int = 0
    for _, v := range array {
        result += v
    }

    return result
}


func mean(array []int) float64 {
    sumArr := float64(sum(array)) / float64(len(array))
    return sumArr
}
```

I didn't achieve the functionality that I wanted to with the above code. **How can I achieve the desired functionality in Go?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need **one extera** receiving goroutine e.g. `getData` and then the `main` goroutine will send the data as it arrives using a channel named `ch`, and you need one **buffered** channel for signalling e.g. `batchCompleted`, and a `WaitGroup` to wait for the `getData` **synchronization**, when it is **done**.
**That is all**, try [it](https://play.golang.org/p/tyi60jpN6-f):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    ch := make(chan int)
    batchCompleted := make(chan struct{}, 1) // non-blocking signaling channel
    wg.Add(1)
    go getData(ch, batchCompleted, wg)

    syntheticData := []int{3, 2, 3, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15}
    i := 0
    check := func() {
        select {
        case <-batchCompleted:
            i++
            fmt.Println(i, " batch completed")
        default:
        }
    }
    for _, data := range syntheticData {
        ch <- data
        check()
    }
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    check()
}

func getData(ch chan int, batchCompleted chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    a := []int{}
    sum, n := 0, 0
    for v := range ch {
        sum += v
        n++
        a = append(a, v)
        if sum == 4*n {
            batchCompleted <- struct{}{}
            fmt.Println(a)
            sum, n = 0, 0
            a = a[:0]
        }
    }
    if len(a) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("remaining data:", a)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[3 2 3 8]
1  batch completed
[2 1 1 1 15]
2  batch completed
```

Comment: Splendid answer. This does the job. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, this should work fine. But not a good solution, though. I've commented out the code so that it's understandable.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Data channel
    ch := make(chan int)
    // Batch close/create channel for signalling
    bsig := make(chan struct{})

    go put(ch, bsig)
    get(ch, bsig, 4)
}

func put(ch chan<- int, bsig chan struct{}) {
    // Listen for batch creation
    go func() {
        n := 1
        // Receives signal from get on the bidrectional
        // channel, and ping back when done on the same
        // channel.
        for range bsig {
            fmt.Printf("Batch #%d\n", n)
            bsig <- struct{}{}
            n++
        }
    }()

    // Steam of numbers
    stream := []int{3, 2, 3, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15}
    for _, s := range stream {
        ch <- s
    }
    close(ch)
}

func get(ch <-chan int, bsig chan struct{}, mean int) {
    num := 0
    sum := 0
    batch := make([]int, 0)
    for s := range ch {
        sum += s
        num++
        batch = append(batch, s)
        // Matches the mean, close batch
        // and signal the sender
        if sum/num == mean {
            // Send ping
            bsig <- struct{}{}
            // Wait for pong?
            <-bsig
            // Print the batch
            fmt.Println(batch)
            // Reset the batch
            sum = 0
            num = 0
            batch = batch[:0]
        }
    }
    // Close the channel
    close(bsig)
}
```